# How to add Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2019 in .NET Core project?

Tags: .net-core, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019

I have installed Crystal Report from SAP in Visual Studio 2019, but it's not showing up in the list to "Add Crystal Report". I want to add into a .NET Core project.

If there is another option to create a Crystal Report, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afaik, your only option is to call another EXE. You can use the [process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-6.0) object for that.

You can use existing 3rd-party Crystal Reports viewers for this. See list [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#viewers). Some of these have a command line API. So you can specify the .rpt file, parameters, export formats, export file name, printer destinations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Crystal Reports is not compatible with .NET Core.
This is because, under the covers, the runtime depends on COM technology.

Comment: Is their any option for displaying Report in dot net core? If its Available

Answer (score 0):

.Net Core is almost useless for database development without reporting support

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have the same issue, but not an answer please press the up arrow and follow the question for answers.